# Issues setting View parameters in View Holder pattern

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I'm using an ArrayAdpater with ListView. I have customized each item with my own layout, which include from top-level view hierarchy, a `RelativeLayout` -> `LinearLayout` -> other inner views.

I'm recycling the view, and I'm using the View Holder pattern. My `getView()` inside the adapter is:

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View rowView = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;

        if(rowView == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);            
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, false);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.tvMessage = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.chat_text_message);
            holder.tvUser = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.user);
            holder.llMessageBubble = (LinearLayout)rowView.findViewById(R.id.message_bubble);

            rowView.setTag(holder);
        }else {

            holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
        }
            setRow(holder, messageList.get(position).getUser(),messageList.get(position).getTextMessage());

        return rowView;
    }
```

Where

```
public static class ViewHolder{
     TextView tvMessage;
     TextView tvUser;
     LinearLayout llMessageBubble;
}
```

and setRow method is defined as:

```
    private void setRow(ViewHolder holder, String user, String message){
        if(user.equals("Me")){

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)holder.llMessageBubble.getLayoutParams();
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);

            holder.llMessageBubble.setLayoutParams(params);
        }else{

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)holder.llMessageBubble.getLayoutParams();
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);

            holder.llMessageBubble.setLayoutParams(params);
        }
        holder.tvMessage.setText(message);
        holder.tvUser.setText(user);
    }
```

When the ListView is shown for the first time, all works good, so I can see my LinearLayout (inside RelativeLayout) aligned to the left or to the right based on the string user.
But something goes wrong when I scroll up and down for a while: after a certain period, all the `LinearLayout`s are aligned to the RIGHT in the Parent. Seems that something is wrong in the recycling.

Comment: does it work without  view holder pattern?

Comment: I have just tried, and NO, I does not work without view Holder pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you keep adding rules to your view. Instead of this:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)holder.llMessageBubble.getLayoutParams();
```

try this (or whichever constructor that fits your needs):

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

Hope it helps.

Regards
Steffen Vangsgaard

Comment: You are right @Steffen. I was missing that the assignment of alignment to right and left are not mutual exlusive, so I can set both parameters as TRUE, but obviously the system apply just one of this (RIGHT should be the default). Thank you!